# How to write a REST Application with AngularJs and jersey

Tags: rest, angularjs, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

i'm new in angularjs and jersey and i need a little help in writing my helloworld REST application...

here is my Jersey

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello Jersey World";
   }
}
```

and here is my controller client with angularJS

```
angular.module('myApp', ['serverApp']);

angular.module('serverApp',['ngResource']).factory('servercom', function($resource){
     return $resource('http://192.168.2.60\\:8080/RestExample/helloworld/', {},
          {query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:false}});
});

function MyController($scope, servercom){

   $scope.temp = servercom.get();
   $scope.text = $scope.temp.name;
}
```

now the problem is when i access my REST service through browser it returns the string and everything is ok...but when i try to access it through AngularJS i get the following message in jersey :

> com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator attachTypes
>        INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String

so whats wrong with my jersey(or angular) code?

Answer (score 3):

AngularJs is expecting JSON to be returned from your resource but it actually returns a simple string which might be a problem.

In the code above, try to return a simple JSON from your resource method, something like

```
return "{\"name\":\"Hello Jersey World\"}";
```

and add "application/json" to the producible media types

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
```

However, I'd recommend switching to Jersey 2.0 (see the [user guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html)) and take a look at the [bean validation example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/bean-validation-webapp) which actually uses AngularJs on the front-end.

Comment: Thanks Michal... i tried what you said but the problem is still here...i tried jqeury instead of angular and its worked well.. i have no idea what the problem is:(